# Livewire V3 Dispatch To Model in Sub Folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working with Livewire V3.
I use the $dispatch('show-post-modal') to dispatch an even
I would live to use the $dispatchTo('customers','show-customer-modal') but my structure is not all livewire element in the default folder.

php artisan make:livewire pages.customers.modal
Pages/Customers/Modal
I would love to dispatchTo('Pages/Customers/Modal','show-customer-modal')

Any idea the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. It uses the same dot-notation as views and such in Laravel.

`wire:click="$dispatchTo('pages.customers.modal','show-customer-modal')"`

Comment: Do that was my first guess but my mistake was I did't include the 
use Livewire\Attributes\On; in my file haha. Thanks !!